# Java stream how to prevent duplication of same value in lambda expression

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java-stream

I have string which I split to hash map

```
String myStrFromUser = "app0=aaa,aaa,app1=ccc,ddd,app3=ddd,app4=iii,ddd,qqq,www,iii";
private static HashMap<String, List<String>> myMap = = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(myStrFromUser.split("(,(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*=[^A-Za-z0-9]*))"))
                            .map(String::trim)
                            .map(s -> s.split("="))
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(str -> s[0], str -> str[1].split(",")))
                            .forEach((key, value) -> myMap.put(key,  Arrays.asList(value)) );
```

The problem is that i like to prevent inserting duplicate values into new `ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value))`

for example :

```
app0=aaa,aaa
```

contains duplicates so I like it to be only 1 "aaa" in the `ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value))`

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of is to create a set out of `str[1].split(",")` then convert it into an array.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: just add [`.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct())?

Comment: @dan1st where ?

Comment: whereever you want to remove duplicates in the `Stream`.

Comment: so you mean i have to do Arrays.stream again on the str[1]?

Comment: @user63898 `new HashSet<String>(Array.asList(str[1].split(","))`. I suggested this solution instead of using `distinct()` because streams won't provide any performance benefit, add a conversion overhead at the end, and the old-schooled style seems to be more concise for me in this case.

P.S. you can argue that distinct has the benefit of abstraction and that is correct and It's better to use a ready-made method than write a one and that is correct too but I don't you should overthink it that much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

- continue to the `toMap` part as you did
- but for the value, simply create a new stream, splitting on the comma and
  converting to a list using distinct to get rid of duplicates.
- I would suggest a `list` over `set` since sets can't be indexed as they are unordered.  If that doesn't matter, convert to a set and remove the distinct call.  And change the Map target to `Set<String>`

```
String myStrFromUser =
        "app0=aaa,aaa,app1=ccc,ddd,app3=ddd,app4=iii,ddd,qqq,www,iii";
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = Arrays.stream(myStrFromUser
        .split("(,(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*=[^A-Za-z0-9]*))"))
        .map(String::trim).map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(str -> str[0], str -> Arrays
                .stream(str[1].split(",")).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())));


myMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
app0=[aaa]
app1=[ccc, ddd]
app4=[iii, ddd, qqq, www]
app3=[ddd]
```

Comment: the toList not working here after the distinct() im using java 8

Comment: use .collect(Collectors.toList()) instead of toList() then. I edited the answer, it should update soon

Comment: I approved the edit.  Thanks!  I was about to do that.  It should work now.

Comment: @user63898 BTW  `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` so you could use that if you wish to shorten your regex.  But nothing wrong with the way you are doing it.

Comment: @WJS you ignored 1 importent thing i need to fill hashmap with forEach ( legacy code) 
also i changed my question now to use List<String>

Comment: @user63898 Why?  That construct has been around since Java 8.

Comment: @user63898 It just ran on Java 8 fine.  And you can also add a tag for Java 8 I think.  Otherwise, most assume the lastest unless specified in the question.